# What is the significance of matplotlib.pyplot.show()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
```

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(a,b)
```

Above code gives same result as the one below

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [1,2,3,4,5]
matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(a,b)
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

**Reframing the question: when to use matplotlib.pyplot.show() ?**

Comment: You are probably running in interactive mode? You'd use `.show()` from a script that's not run in interactive mode or from another interface that shows the plot as it's being modified.

Comment: I'm using Jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use juypter notebook or something else, that shows you the last line of code. However if you run your file with anaconda / pycharm / anything else (console), the line `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter(a,b)` just creates the object and doesn't show it. To show to plot you need to add `matplotlib.pyplot.show()`.

Also, you can "accumulate" charts over the same figure. For example, if you plotting two lines over the same chart - you use twice `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` command, and then to show the figure you must use `show()`